# How can I open Theme Editor in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-theme

So we're making an app with Android Studio for a uni project and I was looking to change the Theme and I found the tutorial on the offical help page (https://developer.android.com/studio/write/theme-editor). Now the problem is, I can't seem to find the Theme Editor. I can't find the 'Open Editor Button' in the top right corner and there is no Theme Editor in the Tools menu.

[image: Can't find Theme Editor]

The only way I found the Theme Editor is using the Help Menu but then I just get an empty screen, not what it should look like when I compare it to the tutorials I looked up.

[image: Empty Theme Editor]

The app I used to take the screenshots is just a test project and not the real project. The version of Android Studio I use is 3.5.1 build on September 25, 2019. I'm new to app development and Java. I hope I was able to make my problem clear and I'm sorry if I made any grammar mistakes as English isn't my primary language.

Answer (score 2):

The official doc showing the warning

> Starting with version 3.3, Theme Editor is no longer included with Android Studio.

This is mentioned in the same [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/theme-editor).

Comment: Thx for the quick response, stupid of me to overlook this. Is there a way to get the theme editor?

Comment: @TheBlackKey, unfortunately, there is no way, even today, almost 3 years later.

Answer (score 0):

From [this explanation](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/av3lhx/comment/ehhmt5q/) of the Android Studio Product Manager

> easonj · 3 yr. ago  Android Studio Product Manager
>
> Unfortunately we had to disable the Theme Editor due to performance
> issues, complexity of maintenance on top of low usage.. We are working
> on a better alternative.

AFAIK, almost 3 years later, there is still no “better alternative”…